Why $\lbrace \omega: \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty X_n \,\, \text{converges}\rbrace$ $ \in \sigma(X_{n+1},X_{n+2},\cdots)$?
We have the definiton of $\sigma-$ algebra generated by random variables $X_n, X_{n+1},\cdots,$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is $\tau_n=\sigma(X_{n+1},X_{n+2},\cdots)$. And I understand it like the set of intersections of sets of the type $X^{-1}_i$(A), where $A$ is a Borel set.
But I don't understand why the set $\lbrace \omega: \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty X_n \,\, \text{converges}\rbrace \in \tau_n$. How could we make it become intersections of sets of the type $X^{-1}_i$(A), where $A$ is a Borel set?
Could you give me any ideas? I really appreciate for your help.

For $\sigma(\cdots)$ you take not only sets $X_i^{-1}(A)$, but countable intersections of those, complements of those, countable intersections of those, and so on.

As an extension, you can think about the fact that ${\omega: \sum_{i=1}^\infty X_n \text{converges}} \in \bigcap_{n\geq 1} \tau_n$. $\mathcal{F}^\ast = \bigcap_{n\geq 1} \tau_n$ is called the future of the process $(X_n)$ or the tail $\sigma$-algebra.

Suppose $(X_n)_{n}$ are real-valued. Let $f_k:=\sum_{n<\ell \leq k}X_\ell,k>n$. We have that $\sigma(f_k)\subseteq \tau_n$ for any $k>n$ since linear combinations of real-valued measurable functions are measurable. But then
$$\{\sum_{\ell>n}X_\ell\textrm{ converges}\}=\{\lim_{k>n}f_k \textrm{ exists in }\mathbb{R}\}=\cap_{u \in \mathbb{N}}\cup_{N > n}\cap_{p,q\geq N}\{|f_p-f_q|<1/u\}$$
The latter is a $\tau_n$-measurable set, and we conclude.

I got it. Thank you very much!
